# Why is it advised give mysql user root@localhost a password?

Tags: mysql, security

When I installed the MySQL server RPM I got this message:

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !

If I can only use the mysql root user from localhost (i.e after logging in over SSH), how does a password provide any additional security benefit? For example, if I'm already the root user I can delete the mysql data directory...

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MySQL `root` user is the administrative user specifically for the MySQLinstance. While it shares a name with the default admin user on Linux systems, they share no commonality except in function. However, the fact that it is the MySQL instance admin *is* the important part and the very *reason* it needs to be protected. Consider the following situations:

**Local Authorized User**
Any person who is given ssh access to your system will be able to log into the MySQL instance as the root user simply by typing `mysql -u root`. Re-read that line again just to make sure it sinks in.

**Remote Unauthorized User**
Any malicious user will be able to gain full control of your MySQL instance simply by exploiting an 'arbitrary command execution' vulnerability. Have a look at [CVE-2009-1151](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/34236) to see exactly how easy this is. In this way they could take control of the `www`, `httpd`, `apache`, or whatever user user and grant themselves a local account. Then log into the MySQL instance as the root user simply by typing `mysql -u root`.

It is for reasons like this that one of the central tenants of Information Security is "Defense in Depth". That is, never trust a single control to protect you. And in this case, give the root user to your MySQL instance a strong password.

Answer (score 1):

Not only root could use root@localhost mysql login, but any local user.

Mysql have it's own accounts, so mysql's root is not same as system root, leaving root@localhost with no password allows any user from localhost to log in as root to mysql, because there's no password.

Answer (score 0):

anyone on the box could run

mysql -u root

and get in.